# Express.js to EJS rendering data partially

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ejs

Imagine the Database like below.

```
// 'Article'  Schema
{ 
subject : 'Hello world', 
content : 'I want to display this content partially. 
           The content would has verbose text like long
           blabla...........blabla.......blabla......blabla...........
           blabla.......blabla......blabla...........b........
           and even more, It would has <img src=".......jpg"/>
}
```

Now I render this data to some ejs file,

```
<table>
<% Articles.forEach(function(article, index){ %>
    <tr>
       <td> <%= article.subject %> </td>
       <td> <%= article.content %> </td>
    </tr>
<% }) %>
</table>


// To don't display verbosely, give style attribute (Of course, on top of html)

<style>
     td { white-space: nowrap; overflow: hidden; }
</style>
```

But this way, It maybe decrease application performance, right? If there are 10, 20, 30 articles on one page, The server will try to display whole of this things. What I want to make is some **summary of contents**, How can I do this cleverly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For summery contents,display initial few text with ellipses in the end

```
<table>
<% Articles.forEach(function(article, index){ %>
    <tr>
       <td> <%= article.subject %> </td>
       <td> <%= article.content.substring(0,10) %> ...</td>
       <td> <a id="read_more" content_id="cont-id" href = "javascript:(void)"> read more..</a></td>
    </tr>
<% }) %>
```

Then use `ajax` application to get complete data on click of `read more` depend whether are you using jquery or angular etc.

And if there are more article then do `pagination` with `ajax application or page refresh`

On node side create API which gives this content data or new articles in the same format that you did during page load

Comment: Thanks ! It's easy and understandable.